# How to keep a specific set of characters from a string using regular expression in PERL

Tags: perl

I have this string

```
 $eq= "ew';@#rfhnbgsu.,/><hdjsdedokk";
```

By Perl I want to extract just the characters `w`, `h`, `n`, `s`, and `f` from the string.

The output should be like this

```
whhfnss
```

Could you help me?

Comment: I'm sorry that's about as clear as mud. Why would that output "whhfnss"? What are the rules? Could you make an example that doesn't look like you've just randomly hit your keyboard with your head?

Comment: Ok I mean extract and print for example just 5 letters (a,h,k,l,f) and ignore others

Comment: But your example doesn't match your input. Order isn't the same for instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
say $s =~ /[whnsf]/g;
```